# sklearn - build own tree object

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I like the way graphviz can display decision trees. But the tree is always built automatically.

What I'd like to do is implement my own set of rules, see how it divides my data and display the result with graphviz.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: You can use graphviz python interface http://matthiaseisen.com/articles/graphviz/